# How to get the first number after a string in bash

Tags: linux, bash

For example, if I have those line in a file called input.txt

name: Tom

age: 12

name: Bob

age: 13

name: Jim

age: 14

name: Joe

age:15

I want the first number after Jim, which is 14. Thanks :)

Comment: Confused over the input... original question asked for number after "weight" where all values were on single... this has now changed to "name" and "age" across multiple lines.

Comment: @Phoebe, With each edit, the structure of file you post is very different, what are you trying to do?

Comment: OK, clear on input now... The output you're expecting... just 14... or all the ages 12, 13, 14, 15... Why is Jim special?

Comment: Sorry, guys, I didn't mean to confuse you. I just need the first number after a target string. Jim is not special , just use it as an example

Comment: Just 14 :D    Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this, using tools including `sed`, `awk`, `cut`, etc. However I prefer `perl`.

```
perl -0777 -nle 'print "$1\n" if /^name:\s*Jim\s*\nage:\s*([\d+.]+)/gm' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- `([\d.]+)` matches any number after the age: on the next line after Jim.
- -0777 is Perl Slurp mode used in combination with /m for multiline matching.

Comment: I just edited my question to make it more clear, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `grep`:

```
cat file.txt | grep -A2 'Jim' | grep -Eo '[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I realized my question is not clear enough, so I edited it :)